# How can I put data into class object when I have to fetch this data using get request in loop?

Tags: api, flutter, dart

This is my code. I need to get 30 class object(number of teams in NBA) with data. In both of API REQUEST there is "teamId". Using this "teamId" I need to fetch TEAM NAME from other requests. That's why I used loop, but this solution is to slow and app doesn't work good. I am looking for different solution. How can I connect this two api requests in the one object? Below the code I wrote.

```
    String year = "2020";
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "https://api-nba-v1.p.rapidapi.com/standings/standard/$year?rapidapi-key=$kApiKey"));

    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var standingsDetails = data['api']['standings'];
      int standingsDetailsLength = standingsDetails.length;
      List<StandingsModel> standingsModel = [];
      for (int i = 0; i < standingsDetailsLength; i++) {
        http.Response responseTeam = await http.get(Uri.parse(
            "https://api-nba-v1.p.rapidapi.com/teams/teamId/${standingsDetails[0]['teamId']}?rapidapi-key=$kApiKey"));
        var dataTeam = jsonDecode(responseTeam.body);
        var teamDetails = dataTeam['api']['teams'];
        StandingsModel standingModel = StandingsModel(
            win: standingsDetails[i]['win'],
            loss: standingsDetails[i]['loss'],
            rank: standingsDetails[i]['conference']['rank'],
            winPercentage: standingsDetails[i]['winPercentage'],
            homeLoss: standingsDetails[i]['home']['loss'],
            homeWin: standingsDetails[i]['home']['win'],
            awayLoss: standingsDetails[i]['away']['loss'],
            awayWin: standingsDetails[i]['away']['win'],
            teamId: standingsDetails[i]['teamId'],
            teamName: teamDetails[i]['fullName']);
        standingsModel.add(standingModel);
      }
      standingsModel.sort((a, b) => b.winPercentage.compareTo(a.winPercentage));
      print(standingsModel.length);
      return (standingsModel);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You shouldn't merge two apis into one function. Have them separate and then use 2 `FutureBuilder`s, one for the main api and other for the individual team api

Comment: @NisanthReddy There's no reason to do that unless the app is supposed to update between the two different API calls. All it will do is add unnecessary boilerplate and complicate the widget tree for no reason.

Comment: @Abion47 Agreed. While going through the question I was doing a simple test using `Future.delayed` and awaiting them one by one. But made a minor mistake which led me to believe `Future.wait` might not have any effect. Thus the comment. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Yes @Albion47 I undestand but in this case I have to fetch from dwo different API calls. I can hardcode it , f.e if teamId = "1" return "Atlanta Hawks". But what if I want to do same operation with players?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are awaiting each individual API call in sequence, so you are waiting for each call to finish before you start the next one, which is going to take a long time depending on how much data you are retrieving and how many teams you have to loop through. A way around this is to split each "team name" API call into its own future and then await them all concurrently.

```dart
Future<List<StandingsModel>> getStandingsModels(String year) async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://api-nba-v1.p.rapidapi.com/standings/standard/$year?rapidapi-key=$kApiKey"));

  final data = jsonDecode(response.body);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final standingsDetails = data['api']['standings'];
    final futures = List<Future<StandingsModel>>();

    for (var i = 0; i < standingsDetails.length; i++) {
      final teamId = standingsDetail['teamId'];
      futures.add(getTeamDetails(standingsDetails, i, teamId));
    }

    final standingsModels = await Future.wait(futures);
    standingsModels.sort((a, b) => b.winPercentage.compareTo(a.winPercentage));

    return standingsModels;
  } else {
    print(response.statusCode);
    return [];
  }
}

Future<StandingsModel> getTeamDetails(List<Map<String, dynamic>> standingsDetails, int i, String teamId) async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://api-nba-v1.p.rapidapi.com/teams/teamId/$teamId?rapidapi-key=$kApiKey"));
  final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  final teamDetails = data['api']['teams'];
  return StandingsModel(
    win: standingsDetails[i]['win'],
    loss: standingsDetails[i]['loss'],
    rank: standingsDetails[i]['conference']['rank'],
    winPercentage: standingsDetails[i]['winPercentage'],
    homeLoss: standingsDetails[i]['home']['loss'],
    homeWin: standingsDetails[i]['home']['win'],
    awayLoss: standingsDetails[i]['away']['loss'],
    awayWin: standingsDetails[i]['away']['win'],
    teamId: standingsDetails[i]['teamId'],
    teamName: teamDetails[i]['fullName'],
  );
}
```